# Person and Group with authority on Spring security

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

Im using grails 2.3.4 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 and as a requisite I need to have groups of permission and user specific permissions without adding groups...

On the docs:

> Please note that when using groups, there should not be a join class between 'person' and 'authority', since 'group' resides between the two.

Is there really no way to do this? If I have that as a requisite should I choose other alternative instead of spring sec? Maybe do it manually? Does shiro solves my problem?

edit: useRoleGroups In config apparently is the setting that makes it get authorities by group only.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented GormUserDetailsService and modified loadAuthorities method with:

```
        if (useGroups) {
        if (authorityGroupPropertyName) {
            authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
        }
        else {
            log.warn "Attempted to use group authorities, but the authority name field for the group class has not been defined."
        }
    }
        LinkedHashSet<Role> ua = UserRole.findAllByUsuario(user).collect { it.role }

    if(!ua.empty) {
        ua.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.authority) }.each { authorities.add(it) }
    }
```